# semantic-ui-react Sticky advertisement (ad follows as scrolling)

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, sticky, semantic-ui-react

I've been having problems with defining a sticky ad, I'm quite the noob regarding react so I might be missing something.

I have a grid with 3 columns - their widths are 3, 10, 3 respectively.
I want to make the left most column a sticky column (will follow user as he scrolls).

When I follow the example on the official docs (https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky) my columns receive equal width (16/3) resulting in annoying spacing between the middle and left & right columns as well as the content in the middle column looking squeezed.

How can I solve this?

I want to do something like this:

```
<Grid>
  <div ref={this.handleContextRef}>
   <Rail position='left'>
    <Grid.Column width={3}>
        <Sticky context={contextRef}>
             <Advertisement unit='skyscraper' test='Skyscraper add' centered />
        </Sticky>
    </Grid.Column>
  </Rail>

    <Grid.Column width={10}>
        <MainComponent />
    </Grid.Column>

   <Rail position='right'>
    <Grid.Column width={3}>
        <Advertisement unit='skyscraper' test='Skyscraper add' centered />
    </Grid.Column>
   </Rail>
  </div>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `<Rail>` element into `<Grid>` element and use `internal` attribute with rail element. Have not tested code but following should work.

```
<Grid>
  <div ref={this.handleContextRef}>
   <Grid.Column width={3}>
      <Rail internal position='left'>
        <Sticky context={contextRef}>
           <Advertisement unit='skyscraper' test='Skyscraper add' centered />
         </Sticky>

      </Rail>
    </Grid.Column>

    <Grid.Column width={10}>
        <MainComponent />
    </Grid.Column>

    <Grid.Column width={3}>
      <Rail internal position='right'>
        <Advertisement unit='skyscraper' test='Skyscraper add' centered />
      </Rail>
    </Grid.Column>
  </div>
</Grid>
```

Another option

```
<Grid>
  <div ref={this.handleContextRef}>
      <Rail position='left'>
        <Advertisement unit='skyscraper' test='Skyscraper add' centered />
      </Rail>

    <Grid.Column width={10}>
        <MainComponent />
    </Grid.Column>

      <Rail position='right'>
        <Advertisement unit='skyscraper' test='Skyscraper add' centered />
      </Rail>
  </div>
</Grid>
```

Also make sure you have `handleContextRef = contextRef => this.setState({ contextRef })` in your class

Comment: What does this do? 

`handleContextRef = contextRef => this.setState({ contextRef })`